# In what episode does Naruto get linked to all the tailed beasts?

Tags: naruto

Seeing as we finished the arc with Fū, I would like to see her reaction again when she actually meets him. So, in what episode does Naruto get linked to all of the tailed beasts and their jinchūriki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Episode 324 ("The Unbreakable Mask and the Shattered Bubble") of [Naruto: Shippuden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto:_Shippuden_episodes_(season_15)). But the fight between Naruto and the other Jinchūriki continue till next episode "Jinchūriki vs. Jinchūriki!!". Until they started getting absorbed into the Gedo Statue.